# Emacspeak for those who aren't visually impaired

Tags: emacs, emacspeak

Is anybody who's not visually impaired using Emacspeak? Are there any tasks for which it is particularly well-suited and more efficient than a visual interface?

Answer (score 2):

If I'm not mistaken, emacspeak have a nice interface to Google's services such as blogger, Picasa photo album, etc., which is probably nice for any emacsen to have.